# Broken image paths on Github Pages (without Jekyll)

Tags: github-pages

I recently pushed a static HTML site to Github Pages. Since it's not a blog, I opted not to use Jekyll. Now, of course, all of my relative image links are broken, and I've yet to find a fix that isn't specific to Jekyll.

1. Any ideas for a fix?
2. Will that fix continue to work once I switch from the username.github.io URL to a custom URL?

Comment: You should use an absolute link when linking images on Github Pages. If you've already tried this and it's still not working, take a look at my simple mistake that caused images to not load. [Case Sensitive Image Extensions on Github Pages](https://www.codewithher.com/2017/08/05/beware-case-sensitive-image-extension-on-github-pages/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly here, but could you not just move the images to the relevant place? For example, if in `index.html` you had

```
<img src="images/photo.png">
```

could you not just move `photo.png` to a directory `/images` in the same folder as `index.html`?

Alternatively, you could change the `img` tags' `src` attribute to instead point to the relevant location.

Both of these would continue to work, *so long as the images are in the same directory as the html file, or a subdirectory of that directory.*

Comment: No, this is a specific issue related to hosting via Github pages. Seems to be well known, but the only answers to the issue that I can find are Jekyll-specific. See [link](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/332)

Comment: That's really weird. On [my page](http://dumbgenius.github.io), relative links (`<img src=icon.png>`) work perfectly. Could I maybe have a link to look at yours?

Comment: With some more digging, it seems to be a capitalization issue that I hadn't noticed. Unfortunately, I'm stuck. I deleted the repo and recreated it, but instead of overwriting the previous folder names that I changed, it just added things back into the repo.

Comment: Gimme a few, might have figured it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dumbgenius. Got it figured out. Had a capitalization error compounded by not realizing that after the first commit, I had to remove the hidden .git file in the directory in order to erase the previous commits from memory.