# images are broken in github pages vignette

Tags: r, pkgdown

I'm in over my head on creating my first package. `build_site()` renders just fine and the site looks good on my machine. When my vignette shows up on github pages, most of the images are broken. I hope somone can point out what I am missing.

Vignette: https://rjake.github.io/simplecolors/docs/articles/Intro.html

Github: https://github.com/rjake/simplecolors

I checked the case sensitivity as suggested here

- [Broken image paths on Github Pages (without Jekyll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611969/broken-image-paths-on-github-pages-without-jekyll)

There is also a pkgdown issue here that I looked at

- https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/172

Comment: What happens if you delete 
`template:
    params:`

Comment: Also, it seems like your reference pages have a different theme than the rest of your site. You might even want to try just deleting `_pkgdown.yml` and republishing the docs to make sure it's a `pkgdown` problem and not a template problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use the `man/` folder. I updated my README to use

`![](man/figures/color_names.png)`

 instead of 
`![](images/color_names.png)`

Comment: But, now `man/figures` are also installed with the package right?

Comment: I wish I understood this stuff better. I don't see `man/figures` in the `.Rbuildignore` but I think I can add it there to avoid this. It seems to only house the logo and the images I'm using in the README

Comment: Came across your question after being frustrated with how over-engineered pkgdown is. It's mysterious to me why everything in `vignettes/` cannot be rendered and just copied over.